# Telemetry data not being received by Application Insights from Azure Functions on Azure Gov

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-gov

Following the guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-endpoints#azure-functions-v2x) I am unable to see any telemetry data from a functions app.

I also tried using [this issues sample Startup](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2263) and had the same result.

I used the default `HttpTrigger` template and first deployed it to commercial and wired up app insights with no issues.

I then tried each of the modifications to the `Startup` and deployed to Azure Gov.  I received no telemetry data from running the function, and it did not connect to the LiveMetric feature.  Oddly enough, for both of the modifications to the start up, when I ran it locally from my machine using the azure functions emulator, it did connect to the LiveMetrics in Azure Gov, but still no telemetry data.

The posed modifications are supposed to modify the telemetry channel and other endpoints to the correct ones, but it appears that it is not working.

Additionally, with and without the startup modifications I tried explicitly setting the endpoints via Application Insights connection string, which had no effect.

Has anyone got this working or know anything about recent updates that would cause the guidance provided by MSFT to break?

#### UPDATE

MSFT support ticket opened, awaiting response.

#### UPDATE (6/17/2020)

MSFT support ticket resolved the issue. The runtime on Azure Gov has been updated and now specifying the correct connection string with `EndpointSuffix=applicationinsights.us` will enable App Insights connectivity.

Also of note, if you've had to previously point the Live Metrics endpoint to `quickpulse.*` to get it to work, that certificate has also been fixed. Specifying `EndpointSuffix=applicationinsights.us` will work there as well.

Answer (score 0):

From azure documentation, "Monitoring via application insights is not supported by azure functions just yet in gov clouds".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/compare-azure-government-global-azure